# If a configurable product has only one option available, should it automatically select it?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, multiselect-attribute

I was wondering what is best practice from the customers perspective.

I have got a few configurable products from our webshop that have only one option available for selection. Should I make this option automatically select the only available option, or should it be selected by the customer?

Please see the image for explanation.

What is the best of the two ways from the customers perspective?

[image]

Comment: Selection is anyway mandatory, I suggest to do autoselect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello Jasper yes from customers perspective it is mandatory to auto-select the colour if there is only one it will increase the productivity of your website.

If you find this answer useful then please upvote this post or mark it as solution thanks.